# How to use CA Signed certificate in Salesforce Production Org for JWT Authentication in connected app?

Tags: integration, oauth2, connected-apps, authentication, jwt

We have a requirement to integrate CTI with Salesforce. We want to create a connected app using Digital Certificate.

For the development orgs we used Open SSL (https://www.apexhours.com/salesforce-oauth-2-0-jwt-bearer-flow/).
But as per security compliance, we need to use an CA signed certificate for the production. We purchased that CA signed certificate but there are no steps mentioned to generate private key. Till now, we followed below steps:
(Setup -> quick find -> Certificate and Key Management -> Create CA-Signed Certificate -> After Creation downloaded it -> Then signed by an Authority > Uploaded it on Prod).

Now we will need the steps to generate the private key for JWT Authentication.

reference: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_keys_uploading_signed_cert.htm&type=5

Comment: You'll never have a CA private key in your possession, you need to rethink your solution architecture.